# Change php to new facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I cant figure out how to change this simple code to work with the newest facebook SDK... 
It seems like they have changed some of the variables, and the way you retrieve information. I have not worked with facebook SDK before and is not that good in programmering. After ready the documentation and trying a few things I still fail. So I hope some of you guys can help me here...

```
require("src/facebook.php");

// construct the object with your facebook app data
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => '[YOUR APP ID]',
'secret' => '[YOUR APP SECRET ID]',
'cookie' => true
));

try {
    // to get the id of the currently logged in user
    // if, you want you can manually set a user id here like this:
    //$uid = '[FB USER ID]';
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    // if you know know the access token before hand then you can set it here
    // or you can leave this line commented
    //$facebook->setAccessToken([ACCESS TOKEN FOR THIS USER - APP]);

    $api_call = array(
        'method' => 'users.hasAppPermission',
        'uid' => $uid,
        'ext_perm' => 'publish_checkins'
    );
    $can_post = $facebook->api($api_call);
    if ($can_post) {
        $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/checkins', 'POST', array(
        'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
        'place' => '[LOCATION ID]',
        'message' => 'I am place to check in',
        'picture' => 'http://test.com/someplace.png',
        'coordinates' => json_encode(array(
           'latitude'  => '[LATITUDE]',
           'longitude' => '[LONGITUDE]',
           'tags' => '[A LIST OF TAGS TO USE FOR THIS CHECKIN]'))
        ));
        echo 'You are checked in';
    } else {
        die('Permissions required!');
    }
} catch (Exception $e){
    // No user found - ask the person to login
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$login_url);
}
```

Comment: So, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

What that code is trying to achieve is not possible anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/checkins

> This endpoint is removed as of Graph API version 2.0

You can only get the user checkins by using the `/me/feed` enpoint, since checkins are now just status posts with a place.

Comment: Oh I see... Can you help me with a code to post a checkin through the new API ?

Comment: there is example code in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed#publish

Comment: just take a look at the parameters, there´s the place. it´s just a simple ID of a place.

Comment: Thanks... I see the code there, and also see how to expand it with a location ID... But I dont know where to put in my code ?
Can you guys quickly make me a working example I can work on... ? I am really a newbie in this.

Comment: why not just open the link i posted? there IS example code in it, just click on "PHP SDK": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed#publish

Comment: i understand that you are a newbie, but you have to learn how to figure stuff out on your own. we don´t just deliver code on stackoverflow, we help you to figure it out on your own, so you learn how it works and how to look for solutions ;)

Comment: I see, and I would like to learn... I came up with this code now:
http://codepad.org/o3IOdzLg

But is getting the error:
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookApp, string given, called in C:\inetpub\www\hotspot.camp\guest\s\9hoc5f3m\fbcheckin2.php on line 56 and defined in C:\inetpub\www\hotspot.camp\guest\s\9hoc5f3m\src\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php on line 97

Comment: you supplied a string where an instance of the FacebookApp class is required. read the docs to know about the required parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0

Comment: you really need to learn the basics of PHP first, that´s very important. else you will have to ask for every single step. make sure you understand the difference between a string an a class instance...